# Relying td events to underlaying tr

Tags: javascript, html

I added an event handler to a tr with the following code:

```
function addRow(pipe, date) 
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    row.insertCell(0).textContent=pipe;
    row.insertCell(1).textContent=date;
    row.value=pipe;
    if(row.addEventListener){
        row.addEventListener('mouseup', touched);
    } else{
        row.attachEvent('mouseup', touched);
    }
    if(row.addEventListener){
        row.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
    } else{
        row.attachEvent('mousedown', mousedown);
    }
 }
```

This the code of the touched and mousedown events:

```
function touched(event) {
   if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv 11/)) || $.browser.msie == 1){
        tr=event.srcElement;
    } else {
         var tr=event.target;
    }
    var value=tr.value;
//console.log("value:"+value);
    setTimeout(function() {
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEEEE";
        setTimeout(function() {
           var pipe=pipes[value];
    //console.log("pipe: "+JSON.stringify(pipe));
           var date=pipe.workdate;
           var measurement=pipe.measurement;
           var order=measurement.order;
           var heat=measurement.heat;
           var lot=measurement.lot;
           var tube=measurement.tube;
           var wallThickness=measurement.wallThickness;
           var outletDiameter=measurement.outletDiameter;
           var lenght=measurement.length;
           var detailUrl="detailTable.html?pipe="+value+"&date="+encodeURIComponent(date)+"&order="+order+"&heat="+heat+"&lot="+lot+"&tube="+tube+"&wallThickness="+wallThickness+"&outletDiameter="+outletDiameter+"&lenght="+lenght;
          //alert("passo: "+detailUrl);
          window.location.href = detailUrl;
        }, 150)
    }, 300)
}

function mousedown(event) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv 11/)) || $.browser.msie == 1){
        tr=event.srcElement;
    } else {
         var tr=event.target;
    }
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "FFFFFFF";  
}
```

and finally this is the style of the page:

```
<style>
    .fixed_headers {
        width: 750px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .fixed_headers th {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .fixed_headers th,
    .fixed_headers td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .fixed_headers td:nth-child(1),
    .fixed_headers th:nth-child(1) {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    .fixed_headers td:nth-child(2),
    .fixed_headers th:nth-child(2) {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    .fixed_headers td:nth-child(3),
    .fixed_headers th:nth-child(3) {
        width: 350px;
    }
    .fixed_headers thead {
        background-color: #333333;
        color: #fdfdfd;
    }
    .fixed_headers thead tr {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .fixed_headers tbody {
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .fixed_headers tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    .old_ie_wrapper {
        height: 300px;
        width: 750px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .old_ie_wrapper tbody {
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Yet when I click on a cell in the table it is itself highlighted but no event on the tr is activated. If on a large screen I click outside the cells, the row event is correctly handled. How do I make the td's transparent so to have all events been caught by the tr?

Comment: In an isolated example, attaching events to rows and cells get triggered as expected ► [http://plnkr.co/edit/gut3YyiuxNBQnTHvhD6W?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/gut3YyiuxNBQnTHvhD6W?p=preview) - If your first line in either, `touched` or `mousedown` event is not triggered there has to be some external reason for this, i.e: Another event bound to the cells or css making cells unclickable?

Comment: There is no event attached to the cells in the JS code and I think neither in the CSS I added in the question. In fact no event is triggered, but for the highlighting of the cell.
Also the example you quoted adds the event handler to the cell, not the row, and that also worked for me but for the unpleasent highlighting of the cell rather than the row as it is the mobile style.

Comment: In the example I posted I attach an event to both, the row and the cells so you can see how it should propagate the event up the chain by default.

Comment: Even your example seems to do nothing when clicking the cell. At any rate once I added the handler for the cells too, the event was not triggered all the same.

Comment: The beaviour is quite deifferent on iOS and Android too; in both cases no event is triggered, but on Android clicking the cell selects it, while on iOS the full row is highlighted..